# Syntax for Google Cloud Gcloud command to setup organization sink filter

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm hoping that someone can guide me as to what the proper syntax for this command would be. Currently, when I run this command with the filter, I get the error: "ERROR: (gcloud.logging.sinks.create) unrecognized arguments: resource.type= project AND protoPayload.methodName= SetIamPolicy AND protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.action =~ ADD AND protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.role =~ roles/editor OR roles/owner AND protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.member =~ serviceAccount"

Here is the gcloud command I am using:

gcloud logging sinks create my-test-sa-sink --organization=##### --include-children pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/my-test-project/topics/PubSubOrgSink --log-filter= "resource.type= project AND protoPayload.methodName= SetIamPolicy AND protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.action =~ ADD AND protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.role =~ roles/editor OR roles/owner AND protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.member =~ serviceAccount"

Comment: try to verify your gcloud logging sinks query to this [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/sinks/create), review and meet all the requirements parameter and try to run again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is occurring because of the extra space between --log-filter= and resource.type= in your gcloud command. Try removing the space and running the command again. Here is the updated command:

`gcloud logging sinks create my-test-sa-sink --organization=##### --include-children pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/my-test-project/topics/PubSubOrgSink --log-filter="resource.type=project AND protoPayload.methodName=SetIamPolicy AND protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.action=~ADD AND protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.role=~roles/editor OR roles/owner AND protoPayload.serviceData.policyDelta.bindingDeltas.member=~serviceAccount"`

This should remove the error you were seeing and create the logging sink with the specified log filter.